# electron-forge --template=typescript-webpack cannot compile sqlite3

Tags: yarnpkg, node-sqlite3, electron-forge, native-module

Using a package that leverages `sqlite3`. It looks like sqlite3 is not being recompiled properly. searched around and saw people recommending better-sqlite3. This would require me to have to port the sqlite3 code (no db.serialize equivalent). Is there another way to get sqlite3 working?

```
❯ yarn start
...
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot open [redacted]/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node: Error: The module '[redacted]/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/node-v83-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 80. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
...
ERROR in ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in '[redacted]/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 52:13-32 184:38-57
 @ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
 @ ./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
 @ ./node_modules/chrome-cookies-secure/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer but [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) supports it by adding sqlite into the /app/package.json.

Comment: This no longer appears to be true. `sqlite3` does not appear in a code search of that repository.